# Tailwindcss show/hide transition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm making a react app with `tailwindcss`, and I want to make a hidden mobile navbar and when the user click on the icon it appears.

So I want to make a transition while the menu appears.

I use:

- React
- Tailwindcss
- Headlessui

My Code:

MobileMenu.js:

```js
function MobileMenu() {
  return (
    <div className="block md:hidden px-4 py-3 text-white w-full bg-gray-800 border-t border-opacity-70 border-slate-700">
      <div className="flex items-center mb-3 pb-3 border-b border-slate-700">
        <img
          src="https://africaprime.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ElonMusk.jpg"
          className="rounded-full w-8 h-8 cursor-pointer"
        />
        <h6 className="ml-5 cursor-pointer">Elon Musk</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="mobile-nav-icon">
        <ImHome size={20} />
        <h4 className="ml-5">Home</h4>
      </div>
      <div className="mobile-nav-icon">
        <HiUsers size={20} />
        <h4 className="ml-5">Friends</h4>
      </div>
      <div className="mobile-nav-icon">
        <CgProfile size={20} />
        <h4 className="ml-5">My Profile</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MobileMenu;
```

How I show it in Navbar.js:

```js
function Navbar() {
  const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="flex justify-between items-center px-4 lg:px-8 py-3 bg-gray-900 text-white">
        {/* Mobile Menu Icon */}
        <div
          className="block md:hidden p-2 cursor-pointer rounded-full hover:bg-gray-700 transition-2"
          onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(!mobileMenuOpen)}
        >
          <FiMenu size={20} />
        </div>
      </nav>
      {/* Mobile Menu */}
      {mobileMenuOpen && <MobileMenu />}
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `@framer/motion` package that allows you easily animate elements.

```
const menuVariants = {
    open: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
    },
    closed: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: '-100%',
    },
  }
```

Animations can be changed however you want according to `@framer/motion` [docs.](https://www.framer.com/motion/)

And attach variants to your `<MobileMenu />` component.

```
function MobileMenu({isMenuOpen}) {
  return (
    <motion.div animate={isMenuOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'}
    variants={menuVariants}> className="block md:hidden px-4 py-3 text-white w-full bg-gray-800 border-t border-opacity-70 border-slate-700">
      <div className="flex items-center mb-3 pb-3 border-b border-slate-700">
        <img
          src="https://africaprime.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ElonMusk.jpg"
          className="rounded-full w-8 h-8 cursor-pointer"
        />
        <h6 className="ml-5 cursor-pointer">Elon Musk</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="mobile-nav-icon">
        <ImHome size={20} />
        <h4 className="ml-5">Home</h4>
      </div>
      <div className="mobile-nav-icon">
        <HiUsers size={20} />
        <h4 className="ml-5">Friends</h4>
      </div>
      <div className="mobile-nav-icon">
        <CgProfile size={20} />
        <h4 className="ml-5">My Profile</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MobileMenu;
```

And you can pass `isMenuOpen` variable as a prop.

```
function Navbar() {
  const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="flex justify-between items-center px-4 lg:px-8 py-3 bg-gray-900 text-white">
        {/* Mobile Menu Icon */}
        <div
          className="block md:hidden p-2 cursor-pointer rounded-full hover:bg-gray-700 transition-2"
          onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(!mobileMenuOpen)}
        >
          <FiMenu size={20} />
        </div>
      </nav>
      {/* Mobile Menu */}
      {mobileMenuOpen && <MobileMenu isMenuOpen={mobileMenuOpen}/>}
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I think because isMenuOpen prop is always true.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You defined in `useState` as `false`. Only way to it can be `true` if you click the div using `setMobileMenuOpen(!mobileMenuOpen)` function. Be sure your MobileMenu's initial position is `l-[-100%] absolute`. If this not solves your problem, what is exactly happening on screen?

Comment: it works normally without any transition, but when I log the isMenuOpen prop into console it always be true, but when log it form the parent components `Navbar.js` it will be false or true depends on the click.

Comment: I don't use relative and absolute method by the way

Answer (score 1):

One potential issue with the provided answer is that state is not being set correctly. See the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) about updating state based on prior state value.

```
<div className="block md:hidden p-2 cursor-pointer rounded-full hover:bg-gray-700 transition-2" onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(prevState => !prevState)}>
```